# Web form sending duplicate emails

Tags: php, html, forms, email, submit

first of all, I know this topic has been discussed in the past but I didn't manage to come to a conclusion, so any help is VERY appreciated.
I know a bit of html but I'm not a programmer, I had someone building a website for me but the web form is often sending duplicate (even 3 or 4 times) emails. I believe (assume) it has to do with people refreshing or hitting the submit button more than once. I tried to disable the 'submit' but I didn't manage to.
At this stage any fix would help. As long as I stop receiving multiple emails from senders.
I will try giving you as much information as possible.
This is the html code for the form:

```
<div class="form-input">
                        <div class="form-title">NAME</div>
                        <input id="form-name" type="text"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-input">
                        <div class="form-title">EMAIL</div>
                        <input id="form-email" type="text"></input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-input">
                        <div class="form-title">MESSAGE</div>
                        <textarea id="form-msg" type="text"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-input">
                        <div class="form-title">&nbsp;</div>
                        <input id="form-send" type="submit" value="SEND"></input>
                    </div>

                </div><!--end of form holder-->

                <div id="details-error">Please comlete all fields and include a valid email</div>
                <div id="form-sent">Thankyou for your enquiry - We will be in touch shortly!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the following is the script I have:

```
// Contact Form Code

    $('#form-send').click(function(){

        var name = $('#form-name').val();
        var email = $('#form-email').val();
        var message = $('#form-msg').val();
        var option = $('#form-select').val();
        var error = 0;

        if(name === '' || email === '' || message === ''){
            error = 1;
            $('#details-error').fadeIn(200);
        }else{
            $('#details-error').fadeOut(200);
        }

        if (!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email))) {
            $('#details-error').fadeIn(200);
            error = 1;
        }

         var dataString = '&option=' + option +'&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&text=' + message;

            if (error === 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "mail.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function () {
                        $('#details-error').fadeOut(1000);
                        $('#form-sent').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }

    });

});
```

And lastly, the mail.php:

```
    <?php
if ($_POST) {
    $name  = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $text  = $_POST['text'];
    $option = $_POST['option'];
    $headers = $option . "\r\n" . $name . "\r\n" . $email;


    //send email   
    mail("xxx@email.net", "Mail Enquiry", $text, $headers);
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe `if (error === 0) { $('#form-send').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You should change the input to a button:

```
<input id="form-send" type="submit" value="SEND"></input>
```

to

```
<button id="form-send" type="button">SEND</button>
```

Because otherwise the form will be submitted once through ajax and then again via the form submit/page refresh

Comment: I'd add `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (error === 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    $('#details-error').fadeOut(1000);
                    $('#form-sent').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
```

This portion of code in #form-send click function is what to do when the submission was successful, you could modify the submit button to disable further clicks if you feel the users are clicking submit after they already submitted the form.

```
$('#form-send').attr('disabled','disabled'); // only disable the #form-send and not other forms that may need to still be submitted.
```

Comment: You may want to change your jQuery selector. The way you have it now would disable all submits on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If the submit button is being pressed more than once then this may work.

Try adding the following line of code right after `$('#form-send').click(function(){`

`$('#form-send').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

This will disable the submit button after it has been clicked once. If the page is reloaded by the user, it will be enabled.

Note: this code has not been tested.